Can mathematics be used to describe, model, or predict consciousness?
Mathematics has proven to be an invaluable tool in fields such as physics, chemistry, biology, and economics. It allows us to make theoretical predictions, which can then be tested against reality—an essential aspect of the scientific method. I was recently made aware of the Association for Mathematical Conscious Science.
But can mathematics be used to describe, model, or predict consciousness?

Related:

Philosophy of AI - Consciousness and Free Will
Could general-AI language generation be a test for sentience, sapience, or consciousness?
Can Mathematics Fully Describe the Universe?
The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences
Is the phenomenom of “subjective consciousness” or “qualia” formally captured by any state-of-the-art Theoretical Model in Physics?


We don't really have a good understanding of what consciousness is, so it seems premature to try to calculate it mathematically.

Michael Hall has apparently deleted the comments you were responding to. I suggest you delete your comments since they make no sense now.

This is a question that is going to inspire a lot of woo knee-jerk by the computers-are-just-bit twiddler crowd. If it gets closed, post it over in Meta and we'll try to get it reopened.

I edited the main question (too many related questions opening up complaints based on "not enough focus") to stave off closure. Feel free to roll back.

Yes, mathematics used in consciousness studies (arizona.edu) is part of the experimental philosophy (SEP) movement, and there are working groups of researchers who do it. Consider the AMCS:

The Association for Mathematical Consciousness Science (AMCS) is an international association of scientists and philosophers devoted to mathematical topics in the scientific study of consciousness. It aims to further the development of mathematical approaches in the scientific study of consciousness, henceforth referred to as Mathematical Consciousness Science (MCS).

The groundwork for the present research in consciousness arguably starts with McCulloch and Pitt's A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity which is about as famous as Turing's paper as it introduced the foundations that were eventually developed in later connectionist work. As Lowri has made clear in her answer, mathematics devoid of grounding in the semantics of a theory is just a tool confined to mathematical discourse. When it is part of a greater theory, it then becomes indispensable as an extension to the logic of the theory.
Of course, modeling neurons is not directly the modeling of consciousness (scholarpedia.org) itself. There are many ways outside of consciousness studies that mathematical modeling enriches science adjacently. For instance, neuronal encoding can be described mathematically using calculus (GB). Cognitive architecture is another science that holds promise for understanding the modularity of mind as Fodor, Minsky, and others have explored.
There is no a priori reason that mathematical modeling of consciousness cannot be conducted. While there is a lot of woo surrounding consciousness, a lot has been learned about which regions in the brain might be considered neural correlates of consciousness. Ultimately, the basic aspects of mathematical modeling will continue to generate insights using creative construction of models, following up with fitting and optimization, exposing the models to empirical constraints, and building dynamics into the system. In fact, there are factions in cognitive science that insist that human consciousness is best modeled with dynamic systems.
Ultimately, AGI researchers like Ben Goertzel, who is himself a mathematician by way of his PhD, believe that we will have the ability to replicate human intelligence with such models. This of course, is a philosophically contentious issue, with the same sorts of factions that emerged after Searle put forth his Chinese Room argument. Ultimately, the brain is rather complicated structure, and it remains to be seen that concepts like Edelman and Tononi's ideas like neural reentry will provide a foundation for such mathematical (read computer) simultations. Certainly if you read Goertzel and Pennachin's (Eds.) Artificial General Intelligence (GB), you will see we haven't really made much progress since Minsky's Society of Mind. The complexity of the brain is hard to overstate!


Can mathematics describe, model, or predict consciousness?

Mathematics on its own does not describe or predict anything without an associated model of semantics or correspondence with the external world.
For example, equations describing the orbits of planets predict nothing without the semantic model we place on top of it.

Can consciousness be derived from first principles using mathematics?

Without scientific theories, mathematics can only speak within its realm.
The search for and modelling (including mathematical modelling) of neuronal correlates of consciousness is an active area of research. Whether this is capable of ultimately producing a predictively useful model of consciousness is an empirical question.

1 consciousness + 1 consciousness = 2 consciousnesses
Proof by existential introduction, mathematics can be used describing consciousnesses.

There is no philosophical reason for my upvote. Making me chuckle is worth it.
